# Display text outside of containing element

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

I want to achieve this. Keep an eye on the top text *'Happy Fruit'*. I want to be overlayed of the box while it's nested inside it.[image]

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: orange;
    box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: red;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="slider">
<h1>
Happy Fruit
</h1>
<h2>
HELLO WORLD
</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

If I then go and add a `margin-top: -50px;` to the h1 the text will stay **inside the div, but how can I make it going above/standing on it** on it while it's still being nested inside (html)? I've tried playing with `z-index` but that didn't work.

```
position: relative; top: -50px;
```

[image]

Comment: `h1 {position: relative; top: -50px;}`

Comment: That doesn't work then this happens (check img in updated post)

Comment: `.slider {overflow: visible;}` Appears to me to be a simple overflow issue, thing is, applying this solution in the provided code snippet works, so if it's not working in production for you, then there are other styles or factors involved that you haven't included in the code you've provided for us to work with and troubleshoot.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError that did the job, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with adjusting the position of `<h1/>`? You can offset the position by adding padding to `.slider`.

```
.slider {
  position: relative; <!-- necessary in case other position is set in ancestry -->
  padding-top: 10px;
}
h1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}
```

If `overflow: hidden;` is set on `.slider`, your header will be cut off. Otherwise the default is `overflow: visible;` and you should have no trouble.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="slider">
    <h1>
      Happy Fruit
    </h1>
    <h2>
      HELLO WORLD
    </h2>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but someone mentioned adding overflow: visible to .slider and that fixed it

Answer (score 2):

Using absolute positioning.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 1.2em;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1.2em;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <h1>
    Happy Fruit
  </h1>
  <h2>
    HELLO WORLD
  </h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linear-gradient` here and for `box-shadow` you can use absolutely positioned pseudoelement (with needed offset).

For example, with `40px` offset `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40px, orange 40px);`. Also we should apply `top: 40px` for pseudoelement.

Demo:

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}

.slider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent 40px, orange 40px);
  position: relative;
}

.slider:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 40px;
  bottom: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
  /* don't overlap container */
  z-index: -1;
}

h1,
h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: red;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <h1>
    Happy Fruit
  </h1>
  <h2>
    HELLO WORLD
  </h2>
</div>
```