# Display element outside the nested div while visibility stays hidden

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-position, positioning

I want to achieve this. Keep an eye on the top text *'Happy Fruit'*. I want to be overlayed of the box while it's nested inside it.[image]

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: orange;
    box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: red;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="slider">
<h1>
Happy Fruit
</h1>
<h2>
HELLO WORLD
</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

If I then go and add a `margin-top: -50px;` to the h1 the text will stay **inside the div, but how can I make it going above/standing on it** on it while it's still being nested inside (html)? I've tried playing with `z-index` but that didn't work.

```
position: relative; top: -50px;
```

**The .slides has `overflow: hidden;` because if it is on `overflow:visible;` the other slides of the slider will show up, like this.**
[image]

[image]

Comment: How is it different from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45418991/1548895)?

Comment: If I add overflow: visible; the text will appear on it which is fine but then on the right (and left) side it will show the slides as it's a slider so that didn't really fix it (I only noticed it after a moment as the second slide is close to be the same yellow.) Also the backgroundgradient didn't do the job

Comment: Can you please check my answer and say what exactly you don't like about it?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is because of [collapsing margin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins).

Add border: 1px solid transparent; to slider class and give margin-top in negative to h1 tag like -40px, as in the code solution below.

```css
body {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 50px;
}
.slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: 650px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    background: orange;
    box-shadow: 0 0 78px 11px #F3286B;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
h1, h2 {
  text-transform:uppercase;
  color: red;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 11vw;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
h2 {
  font-size: 7vw;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="slider">
<h1>
Happy Fruit
</h1>
<h2>
HELLO WORLD
</h2>
</div>
</body>
```